# Install all missing packages under MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex

When I install MiKTeX on a computer, I always choose the option of installing all packages. Of course, as time goes by, new packages appear on CTAN. Is there any way of telling MiKTeX to install all *missing* packages? It seems to be a logical request coming from someone who chose to install all packages.

Comment: No. I regularly update the package database in the console and then sort by the installed column and install the missing ones. You could make a feature request - imho a "autoinstall" option would be nice.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps that you could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I regularly update the package database in the console and then sort by the installed column and install the missing ones. You could make a feature request - imho an "autoinstall" option would be nice.