# Set font style Book Antiqua

Tags: fonts

I am trying to set my paper's style to Book Antiqua. I am using this script:

```
\usepackage{antiqua}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But i get this error:
*! LaTeX Error: File `antiqua.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)*

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: you have to install/update the missing package called antiqua.sty into your LaTeX distribution. You can refer this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523283/install-all-missing-packages-under-miktex (or)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523283/install-all-missing-packages-under-miktex

Comment: There was an `antiqua.sty` among the support files for using the FontSite 500 CD (https://www.fontsite.com/), a collection which seems no longer available.

Comment: Dear @rakatex, how can I do that? I am using teXworks and mikTex, but I am not good at it. 
ps. you linked twice the same question

Comment: If you took your sample code from the LaTeX Font Catalogue, then the package you need to download and install is at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/urwvf/ (this is different from the old FontSite package).

Comment: I am writing my thesis and it is required book antigua with line space 22 or 23 points. I am starting from zero and trying to write all the required params. So I don't have salmpe code besides a lipsum document of 3 pages which says almost nothing...

Comment: Oh.  Book Antiqua was a clone of Palatino.  Save yourself lots of grief and just use TeX Gyre Pagella, which is also like Palatino.  (The history of Palatino is long and complex; enough here to say that no one among your readers will know the difference.)

Comment: Thank you all :)